# How can I quickly encrypt a 128 bit value into another equal length value in NodeJS 14

Tags: node.js, typescript, encryption

My server will be sending many IDs to the browser/user, and, for that session, the user might operate using those IDs.  Between users, and between multiple sessions of a single user, I need IDs to be encrypted, so they cannot be traced except within the context of a single session.  Due to the number of IDs that will be used in each session, it is not reasonable to dereference or hash them and store lookup tables for each session.

The IDs are effectively UUIDs, unique 128 bit values.  The server will encrypt them in the context of a session, and when the user queries using them, and the server can decrypt those values within the context of that same session.  I would *like* for the encrypted output to also be 128 bits in length (for example, so they could be rendered as UUIDs even in their encrypted state).  What is the best way for me to achieve this?

This is my sample code, demonstrating that I can encrypt 16 bytes (the size of a block), but the cipher extends it to 2 blocks, doubling the size to 32 bytes, when I finalize it.  I think because it is OK for a value to be encrypted the same way twice in the context of a single session, it is acceptable to reuse the same IV for each item; so the server stores a key and IV for the session, and can encrypt and decrypt all of the IDs with those.

```
async function sampleCrypt() {
    const algorithm = 'aes-128-cbc';
    crypto.scrypt("samplePassword", "salty", 16, (err, key) => {
        const iv: Buffer = crypto.randomBytes(16);
        const cipher: crypto.Cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
        const inbuffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(16);
        inbuffer.writeUInt32BE(1960); // just some sample data
        console.log(cipher.update(inbuffer, undefined, 'hex')); // loads the whole buffer in
        console.log(cipher.final('hex'));
    });
}

sampleCrypt();

/* Sample output:
83134f7dc2f9b175bd70a7dd0512eaf7
9495e0cfceab0439fddc92f3fffa48c2
*/
```

Please advise if I have made any incorrect assumptions here as well. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's actually possible for an encrypted string to be the same length as the original.

Comment: Is that for AES specifically, or most/all encryption algorithms?

Comment: I beleive it's the case with most/all encryption algorithms. Unless you have some way to encode additional information into the same number of characters, i.e. with a larger possible set of characters etc. Actually I just realised your input is hex, so encrypting and base-64 encoding would effectively allow you to get more information into the same length string, so it might be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Block ciphers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) such as [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) require plaintexts whose lengths are an integer multiple of the blocksize (16 bytes for AES). If this isn't the case, padding must be used. NodeJS applies [PKCS7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) by default. Here a complete padding block is appended if the plaintext length is already an integer multiple of the blocksize. This is the reason why in your case a 16 bytes plaintext results in a 32 bytes ciphertext. But since the plaintext is *always exactly* one block long, there is actually no need for padding. In NodeJS the padding can be disabled with [`cipher.setAutoPadding(false)`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_setautopadding_autopadding), so in your case plaintext and ciphertext are both 16 bytes long.

A block cipher only encrypts *one* block. To encrypt longer plaintexts, an [operation mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) must be used, e.g. CBC as in the posted code. Generally, these operation modes use an [initialization vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Initialization_vector_(IV)) (IV) whose size is equal to the blocksize (16 bytes for AES). The IV must meet certain conditions, e.g. a key/IV pair may only be used once. Since the IV isn't secret it's usually placed before the ciphertext. In your case, this would result in a 32 bytes result (IV + ciphertext). The condition mentioned also means that the concept you use (one key/IV pair for *all* encryptions) is inherently insecure.

An operating mode that doesn't require an IV is [ECB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_(ECB)). ECB generates the *same* ciphertext for the *same* plaintext, which generallay allows conclusions from the ciphertext to the plaintext. This problem doesn't exist for a mode with an IV. Therefore ECB is more [insecure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946) compared to a mode with an IV. However, the severity of this insecurity ultimately depends on the characteristics of the plaintext and the particular application, and the respective requirements determine whether this disadvantage is tolerable or not. 1-block plaintexts containing a GUID are less vulnerable in this respect than multi-block plaintexts with some message content, so ECB may be an option here.

With disabled padding and ECB mode a 16 bytes plaintext results in a 16 bytes ciphertext, as the following *TypeScript* code demonstrates:

```
import * as crypto from "crypto";

const algorithm:string = 'aes-128-ecb';
const key:Buffer = crypto.randomBytes(16);

// Encryption
const plaintextEnc:Buffer = Buffer.from('0123456789012345');
const cipherEnc:crypto.Cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, null);
cipherEnc.setAutoPadding(false);        
const ciphertext:Buffer = Buffer.concat([cipherEnc.update(plaintextEnc), cipherEnc.final()]);
console.log(ciphertext.toString('hex')); 

// Decryption
const cipherDec:crypto.Decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, null);
cipherDec.setAutoPadding(false);
const plaintextDec:Buffer = Buffer.concat([cipherDec.update(ciphertext), cipherDec.final()]);
console.log(plaintextDec.toString('hex'));
```

If the limitation to 16 bytes is dropped, [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) would be a recommendable mode that provides besides confidentiality also authenticity and integrity. GCM uses a 12 bytes IV (nonce) and generates a tag (typically 16 bytes) that is used for authentication. In your case, the result (IV + ciphertext + tag) would have a length of 44 bytes. Note that if a key/IV pair is used more than once for GCM, security is lost.